# Visual Studio Code output pane document updated message - disable

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable these messages? Removing the Output windows from the view settings (right click) doesn't provide a fix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the drop down which in the screenshot says `css-peek` select `Tasks` or something else, that panel is for Output from all sorts of plugins and extensions in VSCode, it will help you understand if something is wrong with those plugins/extensions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Of course it hasn't happened since I posted the question, I'll report back as soon  as it does.